# NPM install express. Error: No compatible version found

Tags: express, installation, npm

My OS is Ubuntu 13.04, 32 bit.

I am trying to install express with this command:

```
$ npm install express
```

And this is the error I get:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: express@'>=4.0.0-0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.14.0","0.14.1","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.3","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.0.6","1.0.7","1.0.8","2.0.0","2.1.0","2.1.1","2.2.0","2.2.1","2.2.2","2.3.0","2.3.1","2.3.2","2.3.3","2.3.4","2.3.5","2.3.6","2.3.7","2.3.8","2.3.9","2.3.10","2.3.11","2.3.12","2.4.0","2.4.1","2.4.2","2.4.3","2.4.4","2.4.5","2.4.6","2.4.7","2.5.0","2.5.1","2.5.2","2.5.3","2.5.4","2.5.5","2.5.6","2.5.7","2.5.8","2.5.9","2.5.10","2.5.11","3.0.0","3.0.1","3.0.2","3.0.3","3.0.4","3.0.5","3.0.6","3.1.0","3.1.1","3.1.2","3.2.0","3.2.1","3.2.2","3.2.3","3.2.4","3.2.5","3.2.6","3.3.0","3.3.1","3.3.2","3.3.3","3.3.4","3.3.5","3.3.6","1.0.0-beta","1.0.0-beta2","1.0.0-rc","1.0.0-rc2","1.0.0-rc3","1.0.0-rc4","2.0.0-beta","2.0.0-beta2","2.0.0-beta3","2.0.0-rc","2.0.0-rc2","2.0.0-rc3","3.0.0-alpha1","3.0.0-alpha2","3.0.0-alpha3","3.0.0-alpha4","3.0.0-alpha5","3.0.0-beta1","3.0.0-beta2","3.0.0-beta3","3.0.0-beta4","3.0.0-beta6","3.0.0-beta7","3.0.0-rc1","3.0.0-rc2","3.0.0-rc3","3.0.0-rc4","3.0.0-rc5","3.3.7"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/home/admin/.nodes/0.10.17/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:719:10)
npm ERR!     at next (/home/admin/.nodes/0.10.17/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:698:17)
npm ERR!     at /home/admin/.nodes/0.10.17/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:675:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/home/admin/.nodes/0.10.17/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /home/admin/.nodes/0.10.17/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/admin/.nodes/current/bin/node" "/home/admin/.nodes/current/bin/npm" "install" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /home/admin/M101JS/Week 2/hw2/hw2-3/blog
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/admin/M101JS/Week 2/hw2/hw2-3/blog/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am new to NodeJS and NPM, so I don't understand the response.
Does anyone have an idea how I can fix it?

Comment: I had this problem recently too, but not sure how I fixed it. Try updating npm to the latest version.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You want to run the latest node (currently 0.10.22). Try these steps to get the newest version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs -y # newer nodejs package includes npm
```

And then try again on `npm install express`.

Answer (score 12):

Update your npm

```
npm install -g npm
```

This was a bug in an earlier version of npm: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4984

You may get warnings when you update. Run the update one more time and you should see a clean npm install.

Comment: A little bit funny, I was looking to solve my problem installing forever@0.10.0 in the Nodejs@0.8.16 and NPM@1.1.69, and then I found your comment. After updating the NPM to latest version (@2.8.3) , the error was gone.

Answer (score 2):

While the solution by @Jim worked well, if you feel the need to update NodeJS, you can do so via the [`n` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n):

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sitting in corporate network then worth pointing registry to your corporate registry/artifactory and trying.

npm config set registry